# Запятые, кавычки, прописные буквы и словоподбор в названии

Tags: пунктуация, лексика, семантика, прописная-строчная, названия

Уважаемые форумчане!

Передо мной встал ряд вопросов в процессе передачи названия **"Танковое управление и что на самом деле означает плохое управление"**. Я буду невероятно благодарен, если вы сможете ответить на них:

1. Правильно ли НЕ ставить *запятую* перед союзом **"и"** в составном названии?
2. Необходимо ли начинать написание вопросительного местоимения **"что"** с *прописной* буквы?
3. Есть ли в данном контексте принципиальная *разница* между словами **"означает"** и **"значит"**? Насколько уместно было выбрать лексему **"означает"**, когда в материале, который следует за названием, приводятся критерии/описание ключевых черт плохого управления?
4. Правильно ли здесь *НЕ ограничивать кавычками* словосочетание "плохое управление"?

Выражаю искреннюю и огромную признательность за разъяснение приведенных моментов. Большое спасибо.

Comment: что такое "танковое управление"?

Comment: @Буратино, танковое управление — система управления в видеоиграх. В ней движение персонажа зависит от положения управляемого игроком героя, а не от перспективы камеры. Самые наглядные примеры работы данной системы: нажатие кнопки **"вверх"** заставляет героя двигаться согласно направлению, в которое он смотрит; **"вниз"** — персонаж меняет направление взгляда и движения на противоположное; **"влево"** и **"вправо"** — протагонист поворачивается (крутится). Типичная вещь для игр эпохи раннего 3D по типу **Resident Evil**, **Tomb Raider** и им подобных.

Comment: Понял, "танковое управление" - это The Tank Controls, только перевод с помощью автопереводчика на русский. Дело в том, что так по-русски не говорят, получается смесь языков и вероятных переводов, и смысл фраз утрачивается, лучше оставить английский The Tank Controls, чем писать "танковое управление", потому что последнее семантическая чепуха.

Comment: Фраза типа "Танковое управление и что на самом деле означает плохое управление" - может быть в чате гиков, которые шарят в сленге игорьков и геймдевелоперов, но если писать текст какой-то более общий, то лучше так вообще не писать и не выражаться, могут не понять.

Comment: Короче, тут проблема не грамматическая, а проблема кривого перевода.

Comment: Варианты выхода из ситуации вижу следующие: The Tank Controls и что на самом деле означает "неудачная система управления" игровым персонажем; либо: Случаи, когда "Танковое управление WASD" является неудачным решением для управления/контроля игровым персонажем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Танковое управление** и что на самом деле означает **плохое управление.***

Вариант записи: ***Танковое управление** и что на самом деле означает **"плохое управление танком".***

1. Правильно ли **не ставить запятую** перед союзом "и" в составном названии?

Правильно, так как  союз ***И*** соединительный: здесь  две **равноправные** темы.

2. Необходимо ли начинать написание вопросительного местоимения "что" **с прописной буквы**?

Нет, **не надо так писать**.  Это правило для **двух названий** литературного произведения, когда можно выбрать любой вариант. Тогда союз ***ИЛИ*** — пояснительный.

**[Розенталь, пункт 5](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=22#pp22)**

```
   Если наименование состоит из двух названий, соединяемых 
   союзом, то с прописной буквы пишется также первое слово 
   второго названия: «Воевода, или Сон на Волге», 
   «Похождения Чичикова, или Мёртвые души», «Дон Жуан, или 
   Каменный гость»
```

3. Есть ли в данном контексте принципиальная разница между словами **"означает" и "значит"?**

Посмотрим толковый словарь **[на Грамоте.ру.](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42).** В первом значении глаголы синонимичны. Но я думаю, что ***означать*** лучше подходит для темы: это не простое соответствие, а подробное раскрытие словосочетания "плохое управление танком".

Об этом говорит, как я думаю, приставка **О**: 1. Обозначает направленность действия по окружности, вокруг предмета, распространение действия на всю поверхность предмета, **на все его стороны.**

**ЗНАЧИТЬ,** нсв. 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать (о словах, знаках, жестах и т.п.).
**ОЗНАЧАТЬ,**  нсв. что. 1. Иметь тот или иной смысл, значение (о словах, знаках, жестах).

4. Правильно ли здесь не ограничивать **кавычками** словосочетание "плохое управление"?

Управление падежом корректное: означает (что?), поэтому в общем случае **кавычки не нужны.** Кавычки должны иметь смысл, например: выделение и подчеркивание; обозначение границ словосочетания.

**[Сравнить с примером:](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/71844906)** ***Объясните, что вообще означает "плохой контроль".*** Это смысловое  **выделение.**

Сравнить: *Танковое управление и что на самом деле означает **"плохое управление танком".*** Это обозначение границ для **распространенного** словосочетания.

Для заданного варианта возможен **авторский** выбор.

Comment: Потрясающе! @Sharon, с огромным и неописуемым восхищением рукоплещу вашему комментарию! Большое спасибо за столь грамотный, последовательно выстроенный и структурированный и глубоко проработанный ответ! Премного благодарю!

Comment: Шароночка, вот только танк оказался не танком, бывает)

Comment: @Буратино  Мог бы и не оказаться))   Танковое управление  https://rctank.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=455

Comment: "Пособие мастеру **вождения** танков" - )) Управление танков называется вождение.) У то выдавали бы "управительское удостоверение" на автомобилисту.

Comment: Еще знак есть:  Знак «За отличное вождение боевых машин автобронетанковых войск»

Comment: =) кстати, там тоже форум 2009 года, и вполне вероятно, что язык уже там начал ломаться на сленг. Потому что в Советском Союзе все же писали по-русски, особенно учебники и название знаков отличия,) а сейчас все читают переводные с инглиша.

Comment: Маршак. "Ни к тому, чтоб стать пилотом,
Быть отважным моряком,
Чтоб лежать за пулемётом,
Управлять грузовиком".  Можно управлять грузовиком?

Comment: @Sharon можно наверное, но обычно такое "управление" происходит в "состоянии алкогольного опьянения". "Управлять" согласно нац корпусу употреблялось в связке "право управлять автомобилем": "Эрцгерцог Леопольд Сальватор в Вене на днях выдержал испытание на право управлять автомобилем, наравне с другими шофферами." 1909 год или типа того. Либо "навык управления автомобилем".

Comment: Потом было еще несколько упоминаний в лит-ре, при описании жизни в Америке: "— Нет, как видно, это не тот гибрид, который нам нужен. Наш гибрид должен уметь управлять автомобилем. Мистер Адамс уже оправился и разглагольствовал как ни в чем не бывало." Ильф и Петров. Потом, у Носова, например: "Это объяснялось, конечно, тем, что благодаря волшебной палочке он моментально выучился управлять автомобилем и управлял как хороший шофер, который даже не думает, что надо поворачивать и на что нажимать, а делает все по привычке, машинально." Типа Незнайка не "водил", а "управлял", не зная как.

Comment: Управлять - подчинять своей воле, а водить - это ездить на авто и соблюдать правила движения. Поэтому управлять автомобилем - значит водить вне правил, по какой-то причине, что уже неправильно.  Управлять - это уметь или знать как крутить руль, скорее, или как педали нажимать. То есть знать, какой рычаг за что отвечает. Ну и типа, если не знать какой рычаг за что отвечает, это ну очень не правильный подход к вождению.

Comment: Поэтому фраза "неправильно управлять" или "плохое управление" - это оксюморон или имеет двойное прочтение. Ну и танк, это не танк совсем.

Comment: С другой стороны вот что они пишут про слово танк: In a footnote, Fuller writes, "This is the first appearance of the word 'tank' in the history of the machine." He writes that "cistern" and "reservoir" also were put forth as possible cover names, "all of which were applicable to the steel-like structure of the machines in the early stages of manufacture. Because it was less clumsy and monosyllabic, the name 'tank' was decided on."

Comment: То есть, из за неуклюжести слов "резервуар", "цистерна" и тп, было принято называть любой контейнер или что-то куда можно вместить, залезть(иногда) стали называть "танк". Англичане склонны к сленгу, такое отношение к языку, это их метод создания общих понятий, что ли. У русских для таких целей - лаконичных звучных названий есть мат, а у них нет. У них нет слов которыми можно назвать любой объект или конструкцию, который всем и так ясно что такое или на что указывает, а у нас есть. Поэтому они танком называют не танк с гусеницами и бронированный, а контейнер, поэтому танкер.

Comment: Хотя и слово "танк" пишут заимствование, и тут две версии, одна, потому что так назвали самоходные консервные банки, а у немцев их называли панзер - то есть броня, или панзер кампф ваген - бронированная военная машина(техника). А англосаксы не парились и назвали "танк" - консервная банка. Видимо потому, что наши воевали за Антанту, назвать танки бронетехникой было не фен шуй, хотя в последствии логичность второго названия тоже стала употребима. Поэтому у нас танк это танк - бронированная техника. А у англичан танк - это любая консервная банка или даже камера в тюрьме.

Comment: Но вот почему относительно управление в игре, тут это вообще просто кто-то не мог сказать "управление персонажем", а выругался по солдафонски, назвав это как в армии учили "tank controls", а пишут они это The Tank Controls. То есть, если буквы большие, то это какое-то специфическое название, а если с артикля the, то это значит сленг - нетипичное употребление и без того жаргонной фразы. Типа "а я называю эту хрень"=the - "управление танком".

Comment: Вот такие фантазии)

Comment: Классные фантазии, зачитаешься!  Я их даже скопировала и убрала подальше, чтобы не пропали. И танки, и ЯЗЫК   –  столько ценных сведений, как раз что мне особенно  интересно!  Нет ли где-нибудь ваших Записок с подобными рассуждениями?  Как то не верится, что нет, а иначе вы не бережно относитесь к своим  талантам)